# Where is ClamAV quarantine folder?

Tags: clamav

I want to restore some files from quarantine after I have executed `clamscan` some times. But I cannot find the quarantine folder in the configuration.

How should I find the address of the quarantined file?

Answer (score 6):

By default, just running `clamscan` only identify viruses in a directory.  To quarantine, you have to set `--move <directory>` on the command line.

I'd look at the script/command you're running.

Answer (score 4):

I use clamtk, the graphical front-end for clamav, in Ubuntu.

I found my folder was named "viruses" and located in `~/.clamtk/viruses` -- that's a hidden folder, of course.

If you have clamav, perhaps `~/.clamav/viruses` or `~/.clam/viruses`, etc.
Try searching for a folder named "viruses", but remember to search in your hidden files and directories.

Hope this helps!

Comment: so basically, clamav moved the file from my pendrive to my PC desktop, and... it left (probably) the file recoverable on the pendrive... I wanted to wipe it (as I just did on my PC), now... that filenode will be troubling to be found. So I guess the best thing is just to scan, and instead of quarantine, just wipe it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should have log where you see lines like:
/some/file: moved to /path/to/quarantine/file

log may be in /var/log/clamav or sent to your email, or console/syslog, depending on syntax you run scan

if you need to restore files to original location - may use a bash script:
https://github.com/Shrizt/clamav-quarantine-recover